# write() bad address

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to write out the **size in bytes** of a string that is defined as

`#define PATHA "/tmp/matrix_a"`

using the code

```
rtn=write(data,(strlen(PATHA)*sizeof(char)),sizeof(int));
if(rtn < 0) 
    perror("Writing data_file 2 ");
```

I get back `Writing data_file 2 : Bad address`

What exactly about this is a bad address? The data file descriptor is open, and writes correctly immediately before and after the above code segment. The data to be written to the file `data` needs to be raw, and not ASCII.

I have also tried defining the string as a char[] with the same issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second argument to `write()` is the *address* of the bytes you want to write, but you are passing the bytes you want to write themselves.  In order to get an address, you must store those bytes in a variable (you can't take the address of the result of an expression).  For example:

```
size_t patha_len = strlen(PATHA);

rtn = write(data, &patha_len, sizeof patha_len);
```

Answer (score 4):

The arguments to POSIX [`write()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) are:

```
#include <unistd.h>

ssize_t write(int fildes, const void *buf, size_t nbyte);
```

That's a:

- file descriptor
- buffer
- size

You've passed two sizes instead of an address and a size.

Use:

```
rtn = write(data, PATHA, sizeof(PATHA)-1);
```

or:

```
rtn = write(data, PATHA, strlen(PATHA));
```

---

If you are seeking to write the size of the string as an `int`, then you need an `int` variable to pass to `write()`, like this:

```
int len = strlen(PATHA);

rtn = write(data, &len, sizeof(len));
```

Note that you can't just use a `size_t` variable unless you want to write a `size_t`; on 64-bit Unix systems, in particular, `sizeof(size_t) != sizeof(int)` in general, and you need to decide which size it is you want to write.

You also need to be aware that some systems are little-endian and others big-endian, and what you write using this mechanism on one type is not going to be readable on the other type (without mapping work done before or after I/O operations).  You might choose to ignore this as a problem, or you might decide to use a portable format (usually, that's called 'network order', and is equivalent to big-endian), or you might decide to define that your code uses the opposite order.  You can write the code so that the same logic is used on all platforms if you're careful (and all platforms get the same answers).

Comment: I don't think your suggested code is quite right.  The OP wants to write out the length of `PATHA` rather than its contents

Comment: That's a possibility — it isn't clear from the question, but maybe makes more sense of the `sizeof(int)`.

Answer (score 3):

The second argument to [`write()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) is the buffer and third argument is the size:

```
ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
```

The posted code passes the length which is interpreted as an address which is incorrect. The compiler should have emitted a warning about this (don't ignore compiler warnings and compile with the warning level at the highest level).

Change to:

```
rtn=write(data, PATHA, strlen(PATHA));
```

Note `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1` so it can be omitted from the size calculation.

Comment: Correct, though not as ASCII text, instead as raw binary data.

Comment: @nos, I see that you are correct. I must admit that never occurred to me and has already been answered.

Answer (score 2):

The `Bad address` error has already been answered. If you want to write the size of a string just use `printf`.

```
printf("Length: %d\n", strlen(data));
```

Either that, or you can write a function that will convert an integer to a string and print that out... I prefer `printf` :)

Comment: I am writing to the file descriptor `data`, the write needs to be unbuffered and raw, not ascii

Answer (score 1):

```
rtn = write(data, PATHA, strlen(PATHA));
```

is what you want I think. Arguments are supposed to be

1. file descriptor (data)
2. the source buffer (your string constant PATHA)
3. The number of bytes to pull from that buffer (measured using strlen() on the same PATHA constant)

Also, to be complete, you should always check rtn for how many characters you've written. You're not guaranteed that you write() all the bytes requested on all descriptor types. So sometimes you end up writing it in chunks, determined by the amount it answers that it wrote, vs how many you know you have yet to write still then.